# Is it possible to use dot notation when props in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a local json object that I can pass to a React class when just calling it by name, but when I try and pass a property of the object, I get an error. Is it possible to use javascript dot notation when using React?

### This is the JSON that works:

```
var Player = {
    {
      "name": "Money",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Market Share",
      "value": 0
    }
  }
};
```

### And the React code that works:

```
React.render(
  <StatsPane stats={Player} ticker={Settings.eventTickRate} />,
  document.getElementById('stats-pane')
);
```

---

### When I try and change the javascript object to this:

```
var Player = {
  "stats": {
    0: {
      "name": "Money",
      "value": 0
    },
    1: {
      "name": "Market Share",
      "value": 0
    }
  }
};
```

### And call the "stats" by using dot notation like this:

```
React.render(
  <StatsPane stats={Player.stats} ticker={Settings.eventTickRate} />,
  document.getElementById('stats-pane')
);
```

### I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You could also post the code with the part that throws error (statsPane.js, line 12). Makes more sense..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to use javascript dot notation when using React?

The error is not in the code you posted. It has nothing to do with React or JSX.

As you can see, the error message points to

```
this.setState({stats: {Player.stats}});
//                          ^
```

`{Player.stats}` is simply not valid a JavaScript object literal. Here is a simpler example that reproduces the issue:

```
> var foo = {bar.baz};
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

I believe you want

```
 this.setState({stats: Player.stats});
```

or something similar.